# Is templating idemotent in ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-template, idempotent

Is the process of simply copying templates to remote host idepomdent? 
Example:

```
- name: Template a file to /etc/files.conf
  template:
    src: /mytemplates/foo.j2
    dest: /etc/file.conf
    owner: bin
    group: wheel
    mode: '0644'
```

Example of template

```
Hello world {{ test_variable }}
```

Comment: It depends on the template.

Comment: Depends on template means, if the template changes during next runs?

Comment: Can you please give an example of them before downvoting? That is exactly the question. Example of template: 
`Hello world {{ test_variable }}`

Comment: The template is idempotent.

Comment: More specifically, for 1 given value in `test_variable`, you will always write the same result. Your task will report 'changed' on first run and 'ok' on subsequent runs (if the file on remote was not changed by an other mean).